# session state service failed prism (Windows store app)

Tags: prism

I am trying to react to suspend events within my Windows Store App. I added the appropriate callback method, but I've run into a problem:

```
App.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;

void Current_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e){}
```

The problem is that, when I trigger the suspension event in Visual Studio and the callback method is called (I have checked it with a breakpoint), it immediately terminates with an Exception:

> session state service failed.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Prism as I was this can happen when the SessionStateService chokes on serializing an object. Relevant navigation parameters and anything manually added get serialized at app termination or suspension. In my specific case i had a non-nullable enum that wasn't being set on an object used as a navigation parameter. I used the following to verify the DataContractSerializer wasn't having issues with object.

```
test.Add("testitem", new WorkflowStep());
MemoryStream sessionData = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
serializer.WriteObject(sessionData, test);
```